The countability of the Cantor-Bendixson rank in Polish spaces
I've been studying the Cantor-Bendixson theorem and have some questions about the proof of the countability of the Cantor-Bendixson rank in Polish spaces. I would greatly appreciate your insights on this.
Let me begin by stating the relevant definitions and concepts:

For a topological space $X$ and a subset $A \subseteq X$, the Cantor-Bendixson derivative of $A$, denoted $A'$, is the set of all limit points of $A$.

We can define a transfinite sequence of sets $(A^{(\alpha)})$ as follows:

$A^{(0)} = A$
$A^{(\alpha+1)} = (A^{(\alpha)})'$
For a limit ordinal $\lambda$, $A^{(\lambda)} = \bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda} A^{(\alpha)}$


The Cantor-Bendixson rank of A is the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $A^{(\alpha)} = A^{(\alpha+1)}$.

A Polish space is a separable, completely metrizable topological space.


Now, my understanding is that for a closed subset $A$ of a Polish space $X$, the Cantor-Bendixson rank of $A$ is countable. However, I'm having difficulty reconciling this with the following line of reasoning:

In a Polish space $X$, the sequence $A^{(\alpha)}$ forms a strictly decreasing sequence of closed sets. Consequently, $X \setminus A^{(\alpha)}$ forms a strictly increasing sequence of open sets in X:
$X \setminus A^{(0)} \subset X \setminus A^{(1)} \subset X \setminus A^{(2)} \subset ... \subset X \setminus A^{(\alpha)}$

Since X is a Polish space, it has a countable basis $\mathcal{B} = \{B_n : n \in \omega\}$. Therefore, for each ordinal $\beta$, we can express $X \setminus A^{(\beta)}$ as a union of basis elements:
$X \setminus A^{(\beta)} = \bigcup\{B_n : n \in I_\beta\}$, where $I_\beta \subseteq \omega$

This leads to a strictly increasing sequence of open sets:
$\bigcup\{B_n : n \in I_0\} \subset \bigcup\{B_n : n \in I_1\} \subset \bigcup\{B_n : n \in I_2\} \subset ... \subset \bigcup\{B_n : n \in I_\alpha\}$

Due to the strict inclusion, the index sets $I_\beta$ must be pairwise distinct.

However, there are $2^{\omega}$ possible subsets of $\omega$, which is uncountable.


This reasoning seems to suggest that $\alpha$ could potentially be uncountable, which contradicts the claim that the Cantor-Bendixson rank is always countable for Polish spaces.
I would be very grateful if you could help me understand where this line of thinking goes wrong, or if there's a fundamental misunderstanding in my approach.
Thank you for your time and expertise.

Due to strict inclusion, from each index set $I_\beta$ you can pick a natural number $k$ that is not in any of the previous index sets. If $\alpha$ was uncountable then you would get an uncountable collection of natural numbers which is impossible.

Your logical thinking is commendable. However, while one step is feasible, ensuring the same for all previous steps ("that is not in any of the previous index sets") is questionable. Through official proof, it can be demonstrated that the basic open sets $B_i$, each containing an isolated point, are "pairwise distinct" at each step and also all previous steps. As these basic open sets are countable, it implies that $\alpha$ is countable. Nevertheless, this explanation suggests that stricter conditions are necessary to establish the "pairwise distinct" property of $I_{\beta}$.
